# Adsense ruins mobile's Pagespeed score, mobile 50, desktop 98

Tags: adsense

When I remove adsense code, both scores 100. Can somebody help me to speedup adsense code on mobile? or i just have to live with it?

Answer (score 0):

Adsense is a third-party network that loads third party codes, you have no control over their resources. Adsense ad scripts, images and css files are poorly optimized.
What you can do is to consider lazy loading ads. Or Live with it.